# Pyspark failed to write into oracle with mixed column types from parquet

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to read 15 parquet files from s3 location and load into oracle database. one of the column 'col2' has mixed 'bigint' and 'double' in it.

Source s3 and oracle table both has 50 columns and i need to load only 2 columns and left other columns default.

[image]

Able to load individual parquet files successfully into oracle database where oracle has column type numeric(38).

Can you please help how to load all 15 files at a time

Comment: It would help if you defined what you are using to do the data transfer (spark?) I don't necessarily have an answer but a question - did this data come from a database originally? Because this is one of the downfalls of taking "strongly typed" data from a database, putting into a "generically typed" store like parquet, then trying to load it back into a database. One solution could be to use spark to  reprocess the offending files and rewrite with a consistent data type

Comment: Is the inconsistent column one of the two columns you are interested in?